# Partial view load with ajax for Iframe facebook app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, facebook-c#-sdk

**Trying to Render a Partial View using Jquery for an ASP.NET MVC Facebook App,** i keep getting **X-Frame-Options: Deny.**
Here is what i see on the response header, firebug shows this request with red font.

```
x-xss-protection:   0
X-Frame-Options:    DENY
X-Firefox-Spdy: 3
x-fb-debug: gG2lr3dx460A0/cvtfzZKxmfepqa2PcBqsiXur3C9Pk=
x-content-type-options: nosniff
Pragma: no-cache
p3p:    CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
Expires:    Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Date:   Mon, 30 Dec 2013 20:54:00 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding:   gzip
Cache-Control:  private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

Here is my jquery call

$.post(myUrl, function (data) {
            $('#detailsDiv').replaceWith(data);
        });

**if i use anchor tag with full page reload it works. But that is not what i want, i want to render the partial view using Jquery call.**

```
<a target="_top"  href="@GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppUrl@Url.Action("GetFriends", "Home")">Test me please</a>
```

Comment: in your question you mention iframe but in your code I don't see an iframe anywhere.  Is this partial in the iframe?

Comment: its the iframe provided by facebook canvas app. yes its partial view load inside iframe